# How can I retrieve the current error handler?

Tags: php

I'd like to find out what error handler is currently, well, handling errors.

I know that [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) will return the previous error handler, but is there a way to find out what the current error handler is without setting a new one?

Comment: Take a look at this php feature request [add get_error_handler and get_exception handler](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54033).

Comment: See my answer below. There's an idempotent solution using `set_error_handler()` until `get_error_handler()` works.

Comment: Please comment and upvote: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible in PHP - as you said, you could retrive the current error handler when you call set_error_handler and restore it with restore_error_handler

Answer (score 26):

Despite the lack of a `get_error_handler()` function in PHP, you can use a little trickery with `set_error_handler()` to retrieve the current error handler, although you might not be able to do much with that information, depending on it's value. Nonetheless:

```php
set_error_handler($handler = set_error_handler('var_dump'));
// Set the handler back to itself immediately after capturing it.

var_dump($handler); // NULL | string | array(2) | Closure
```

Look, ma, it's idempotent!

Comment: Same as the other answer, but with an actual code sample that is usable as-is. +1 :)

Comment: Each run of this will leave an extra two entries on the error handler stack (the stack that's popped by `restore_error_handler()`). The old error handler should be restored with `restore_error_handler()` instead of `set_error_handler()` so the stack is left the same.

Comment: Brill. Can I ask a supremely dumb question. Does the registered error handler stay "current" through many php pages/scripts or does it have to be reset for each one? TIA Steve

Comment: As Jesse pointed out, this has the effect of pushing that `var_dump` onto the stack on each invocation... Within the current request. Once the request completes and the script dies, the error handler for the next request will follow the configured value instead.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is a way to find out the error handler without setting up new one. This is not the one step native php function. but its effects are exactly that what you need.

summarizing all suggestions of @aurbano, @AL the X, @Jesse and @Dominic108 replacement method can look like this

```
function get_error_handler(){
    $handler = set_error_handler(function(){});
    restore_error_handler();
    return $handler;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `set_error_handler()`. `set_error_handler()` returns the current error handler (though as 'mixed'). After you retrieved it, use `restore_error_handler()`, which will leave it as it was.

Comment: I specifically asked if there was a way to find out what the current error handler is without setting a new one.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve without setting a new one. Although calling the two of them in a row would be the only way of getting what you need.

Comment: If there is no way to do it, then that's the answer: ignoring what I already said in my question and offering it as a solution is not useful.

Comment: @user113292 If you use restore_error_handler and set_error_handler, you're not setting a new one, you're using an existing one.

Comment: Chevi's answer is good. Setting a new handler will return the current one. After that just undo the setting of the new handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception {}

set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e){
    echo "Old handler:".$e->getMessage();
});

$lastHandler = set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e) use (&$lastHandler) {
    if ($e instanceof MyException) {
        echo "New handler:".$e->getMessage();
        return;
    }

    if (is_callable($lastHandler)) {
        return call_user_func_array($lastHandler, [$e]);
    }

    throw $e;
});
```

Trigger the exception handler:

```
throw new MyException("Exception one", 1);
```

Output: `New handler:Exception one`

```
throw new Exception("Exception two", 1);
```

Output: `Old handler:Exception two`

Answer (score 0):

one can also use https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342227 for getting the last exception handler:

```
function get_exception_handler()
{
    $handler = set_exception_handler(function () {});
    restore_exception_handler();
    return $handler;
}
```

this might be useful if you want - eg in a unit test - which exception handler has been registered.

Answer (score -4):

I check the source and the answer is no.

Comment: Oh please, you must be better than that.